# Fixed header with floatThead not resizing after browser shrink

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When using the [floatThead plugin](https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead) everything is looking good except when I use the browser's "Maximize/Restore Down" button. When I maximize, it looks good; however when I "restore down" the table doesn't scale to the correct size and the last column is partially hidden. THEN if you click and drag the browser just slightly, the table will adjust to the proper size.

[Here's a fiddle that shows this behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/DxX2T/7/). I'm seeing this behavior in IE10, Chrome and FireFox.

```
var $table = $('.myTable');
$table.floatThead({
    //debounceResizeMs: 300,
    scrollContainer: function ($table) {
        return $table.closest('.wrapper');
    }
});
```

I tried setting the `debounceResizeMs` property to <strike>slow</strike> delay the resize a bit, but that didn't resolve this issue. [I know the plugin's developer is aware of the issue](https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead/issues/57), but this seems like a popular plugin, so I'm guessing someone else has encountered this problem and hopefully found a resolution because I'm out of ideas.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This behavior appears to be isolated to Windows machines. The floatThead developer is working on a fix. For Mac users, here's what I'm seeing on Windows 7 using Chrome

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWoHkwcHc64

Comment: Sorry Mark, I was unable to reproduce on Mac, are you experiencing this on Windows?

Comment: @Tomanow - Interesting. I'm on Windows 7 and I've seen this on multiple computers. What browser did you try? All of those listed?

Comment: I have no doubt that you are experiencing the issue, I am just unable to reproduce it on Chrome in OS X environment. Maybe research a windows-specific issue that could be related, you might find out how to fix it without including the plugin details in your search.

Comment: script author here - it was fixed a few versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

add the following into the $(window).resize() event

```
$('#id').floatThead('reflow')
```

this works for me...

Comment: you don't need to do this. the plugin already does this internally. There was a bug a few versions ago that prevented this from happening on windows. It has been fixed.

Comment: Still happens in some circumstances.  I wrapped the "reflow" in a setTimeout and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

set 'autoReflow' to true as shown below

```
var $table = $('.myTable');
$table.floatThead({
    //debounceResizeMs: 300,
    position: 'auto',
    autoReflow: true,
    scrollContainer: function ($table) {
        return $table.closest('.wrapper');
    }
});
```